# I just installed Ubuntu 14.04 and I cannot see any wifi connections

Tags: 14.04

I have installed 14.04 recently. And when I try to connect to wireless network it does not show up any WiFi signal. Please help I am new to Ubuntu!

Also please note terminal returned no wireless extensions on `iwconfig` query!!

> system specification:
>
> Lenovo E49
>   64bit
>   2Gb RAM
>   Intel Celeron CPU(R)b830@1.80Ghz x 2

Comment: Please follow the [instructions for Wifi issue diagnostics](/q/425155) and [edit] your question to include a link to the results.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that your Wi-Fi adapter is in working condition in other OS (i.e. Windows).
So just go for the following check marks:

1. Check for hard switch check:
   `rfkill list all`
   if it shows hard/soft block, resolve it:
   `rfkill unblock all`

   [relevant`rfkill` explanation](http://wireless.kernel.org/en/users/Documentation/rfkill)
2. If doesn't work go for driver check for that here is the link:
   [WifiDocs/WirelessTroubleShootingGuide/Drivers](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WifiDocs/WirelessTroubleShootingGuide/Drivers)

It covers all the details how to resolve the issue resolve the driver issue.
After all this still it doesn't work then may be something went wrong with your hardware.

Answer (score 0):

As stated here, Ubuntu 12.04.2 LTS is the best version of Ubuntu to have on Lenovo E49: http://www.ubuntu.com/certification/hardware/201202-10573/

This means that as you have got a latter version, that some hardware will not work, so you will need to find the correct Wifi driver and install it. And as it says in the link:

```
Installation of proprietary drivers is required for WiFi functionality. When prompted to install drivers, select the "Broadcom STA" driver.
```

This means that as you got a latter version of Ubuntu that you were not provided with this option. This also means that that is the Wifi driver which you need.

So you can get the correct Wifi driver you need here (look in the "Broadcom STA Wireless driver (Proprietary)" section): https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WifiDocs/Driver/bcm43xx#Broadcom_STA_Wireless_driver_.28Proprietary.29

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully your device is supported by the b43 driver. Check [this site](http://wireless.kernel.org/en/users/Drivers/b43) and use the command `lspci -vnn -d 14e4:` to see which adapter you have. These devices are supported:
[image]

If you have a compatible device, then you must hook this machine up to a wired Internet connection and run this command:

```
sudo apt-get install firmware-b43-installer
```

When you reboot, you should be able to see WiFi networks with the network manager.